# Change the order of tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

Currently i am working on a tabbed application that contains 3 tabs and i was wondering if there's a possibility to change the order of the tabs, i.e to put the third tab in the place of the first tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UITabBarController *tabController;
NSArray *controllers = tabController.viewControllers;
NSArray *reorderedControllers = [controllers sortedArrayUsingComparator:yourComparator];
[tabController setViewControllers:reorderedControllers];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change it in the Storyboard. It's easy to modify the XML for something small like this. Open up the Storyboard file in your editor of choice and search for 'tabBarController'. You'll find something like this:

`<connections>
    <segue destination="XmF-SX-cO9" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="CZB-Ec-d55"/>
    <segue destination="mCx-nD-74Q" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="3PE-EG-9Vs"/>
    <segue destination="bxy-1d-KHG" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="OP9-xt-ZMo"/>
    <segue destination="JqF-xj-sCJ" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="cHB-MZ-3bs"/>
</connections>`

That represents the current order of your tabs. If you want to switch the first and the second tabs, simply switch their places in this list. It's as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current viewControllers out of the tabbar via the property

```
NSArray *viewControllers = myTabBarController.viewControllers;
```

And the reorder the viewController in the array e.g.by hand:

```
NSArray *newOrderedViewController = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewControllers[2],viewControllers[0],viewControllers[1],viewControllers[3], nil];
```

and finally set the new orderd view controller.

```
myTabBarController.viewControllers = newOrderedViewController;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked just well. But i also figured that it works also by just changing the order like this: self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav, viewController1, viewController2,nil];

Comment: thats right. If you have got pointers to the view controllers you can directly sort them in the new array. Glad I could help.